# Small context errors

Tags: c#

Can't really figure out what's wrong with this code, would be glad if someone could take a quick look on it! Probably just some simple errors I guess, mostly context errors..
Sorry for the swedish!
Thanks!

I'm getting these errors:

Error   CS0103  The name 'flaskor' does not exist in the current context

This happens to add_soda, print_crate, calc_total, antal_flaskor aswell

Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Error   CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

```
using System;

namespace sodacrate
{
class Sodacrate
{
    private string[] flaskor = new string[24];
    private int antal_flaskor = 0;
    public int sum = 0;

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("|*|Välkommen till läskbacken!|*|");

        int temp = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("|*|Välj ett alternativ|*|");
            Console.WriteLine("/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/");
            Console.WriteLine("(1): Lägg till en läsk");
            Console.WriteLine("(2): Skriv ut innehållet i läskbacken");
            Console.WriteLine("(3): Beräkna totala värdet på läskbacken");
            Console.WriteLine("(4): Avsluta programmet");

            temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (temp)
            {
                case 1:
                    add_soda();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    print_crate();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    calc_total();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Programmet avslutas...");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ogiltig inmatning");
                    break;
            }
        } while (temp != 0);
    }
}

public void add_soda()
{
    if (antal_flaskor == 24)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Läskbacken är full, du kan inte lägga till fler flaskor!");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("    |*|*|~MENY~|*|*|");
    Console.WriteLine("    Välj valfri läsk");
    Console.WriteLine("/------------------/");
    Console.WriteLine("(1): Coca-Cola   5kr");
    Console.WriteLine("(2): Fanta       5kr");
    Console.WriteLine("(3): Sprite      5kr");
    Console.WriteLine("(4): Pepsi       5kr");
    Console.WriteLine("(5): Trocadero   5kr");
    Console.WriteLine("/------------------/");

    int temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    bool meny = true;

    do
    {
        switch (temp)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Coca-Cola");
                meny = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Fanta");
                meny = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Sprite");
                meny = false;
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("Pepsi");
                meny = false;
                break;
            case 5:
                Console.WriteLine("Trocadero");
                meny = false;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Ogiltig inmatning");
                meny = false;
                break;
        }
    } while (meny);
    Console.WriteLine("Tryck för att återgå till menyn...");
}
}

public void print_crate()
{
foreach (var dryck in flaskor)
{
    if (dryck != null)
        Console.WriteLine(dryck);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Ledig");
}
}

public int calc_total()
{
int total = 0;

foreach (var dryck in flaskor)
{
    if (dryck != null)
        total += 5;
}
return total;
}
}

class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sodacrate = new Sodacrate();
    sodacrate.Run();
    Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Couple quick tips. First, there's no need to put the language in the title of the question. We already have the question tagged. I'll remove it.

Comment: Second, start following C# naming conventions as soon as possible. Notice that it is `Console.WriteLine`, not `console.write_line`, so similarly, your code should be `AddSoda`, not `add_soda`.

Comment: Third **never name a class the same as its namespace**. Never say `namespace SodaCrate { class SodaCrate { ...`  This can cause a *lot* of confusion because both humans reading the code and the tooling can get completely mixed up as to whether you mean the class or the namespace.  Namespaces are used to add clarity to a large collection of classes; if you don't need it, eliminate it. If you do need it, make it a more general name for the namespace.

Comment: Fourth, a small productivity tip, you can replace     `if (dryck != null)
        Console.WriteLine(dryck);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Ledig");` with `Console.WriteLine(dryck??"Ledig");`

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Will keep them in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to write your methods outside the class but inside the namespace.
This is not allowed!

Here are some of the problems, with a comment, please be more rigorous to define exactly one closing bracket for every opening bracket:

```cs
// [...]

        } while (temp != 0);
    }
} // <== this one closes the class, you should move it after all methods!

public void add_soda()
{

// [...]

    Console.WriteLine("Tryck för att återgå till menyn...");
}

} // <== this one closes the namespace, you should move it after the whole code!

public void print_crate()
{

// [...]
```

Also notice that you need a `using sodacrate;` to create a new object of Sodacrate in your Program class!

Comment: Instead of copying the whole code, maybe it's better to focus and show only the lines that are the cause of the problem, and the lines after correction.

Comment: Sorry I am new here. I'd love to do that if you would explain how I would do that best.

Comment: I have edited your answer so that you better understand what I mean. Tell me if you're okay, or if you want to revert to your initial proposition.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for showing me! :)

Answer (score 0):

i have rearrange the codes:

```
using System;

namespace sodacrate
{
    public class Sodacrate
    {
        private string[] flaskor = new string[24];
        private int antal_flaskor = 0;
        public int sum = 0;

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("|*|Välkommen till läskbacken!|*|");

            int temp = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("|*|Välj ett alternativ|*|");
                Console.WriteLine("/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/~*/");
                Console.WriteLine("(1): Lägg till en läsk");
                Console.WriteLine("(2): Skriv ut innehållet i läskbacken");
                Console.WriteLine("(3): Beräkna totala värdet på läskbacken");
                Console.WriteLine("(4): Avsluta programmet");

                temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (temp)
                {
                    case 1:
                        add_soda();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        print_crate();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        calc_total();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Programmet avslutas...");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ogiltig inmatning");
                        break;
                }
            } while (temp != 0);
        }

        public void add_soda()
        {
            if (antal_flaskor == 24)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Läskbacken är full, du kan inte lägga till fler flaskor!");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("    |*|*|~MENY~|*|*|");
            Console.WriteLine("    Välj valfri läsk");
            Console.WriteLine("/------------------/");
            Console.WriteLine("(1): Coca-Cola   5kr");
            Console.WriteLine("(2): Fanta       5kr");
            Console.WriteLine("(3): Sprite      5kr");
            Console.WriteLine("(4): Pepsi       5kr");
            Console.WriteLine("(5): Trocadero   5kr");
            Console.WriteLine("/------------------/");

            int temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bool meny = true;

            do
            {
                switch (temp)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Coca-Cola");
                        meny = false;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Fanta");
                        meny = false;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Sprite");
                        meny = false;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Pepsi");
                        meny = false;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Trocadero");
                        meny = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ogiltig inmatning");
                        meny = false;
                        break;
                }
            } while (meny);
            Console.WriteLine("Tryck för att återgå till menyn...");
        }

        public void print_crate()
        {
            foreach (var dryck in flaskor)
            {
                if (dryck != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(dryck);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Ledig");
            }
        }

        public int calc_total()
        {
            int total = 0;

            foreach (var dryck in flaskor)
            {
                if (dryck != null)
                    total += 5;
            }
            return total;
        }

    }
}



class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sodacrate = new sodacrate.Sodacrate();
        sodacrate.Run();
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```